# converting pdf pictures to png files makes pictures too small

Tags: pdf, images, conversion, imagemagick

I'm converting a bunch of pdf vector figures to png files.

```
for f in *.pdf
   do convert -trim ${f} "${f}.png"
done
rename 's/\.pdf//' *.png
```

But the dimension of the pictures are too small.

The doc of `convert` tells a `-size width height` option but I cannot specify a unique size for all pictures. Any other ways?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `-density` option to define how many pixels you want per inch; the default is `-density 72`.

Also, since you're using Bash, you can directly manipulate the file name in the loop:

```
for src in *.pdf ; do
    convert -trim "${src}" "${src%.*}.png"
done
```

without having to do a post-rename. `${src%.*}` in Bash evaluates to the contents of `src`, but with everything following a final `.` removed. (If `src` does not contain `.`, `${src%.*}` evaluates to the same as `$src`.)